# Using multiple memcache servers in a pool

Tags: python, memcached

I'm going through the documentation and I'm a little confused as to how memcache does internal load-balancing if multiple servers are specified.  For example:

```
import memcache
mc.set_servers(['127.0.0.1:11211','127.0.0.1:11212',])
mc.set("some_key", "Some value")
print mc.get("some_key")
```

Will the setting and retrieval of key "some_key" always hit the same server?  Will the setting and retrieval of alternate keys, such as "some_key_2" or "some_key_3," automatically be distributed amongst the pool of servers?  What happens if a server is added or deleted?

Similarly, what happens with get_multi:

```
import memcache
mc.set_servers(['127.0.0.1:11211','127.0.0.1:11212',])
mc.set_multi({42: 'adams', 46 : 'and of me'})
print mc.get_multi([46, 42])
```

Will this automatically set and retrieve each key from the right server?  Is it necessary to write a wrapper class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

memcached places keys on servers based on a hash of the key. As long as your server setup doesn't change, then a given key will always land on a given server.

Comment: Right, so it will transparently do this if there are multiple servers in the pool?  get_multi() will automatically retrieve the right keys from the right servers?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do - the memcached library does that under the covers. If it's not doing it, then there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: That's great ... I didn't know it automatically did this.  I thought I had to write a wrapper class. Thanks.

Comment: Am I right in saying that, whenever a new cache server is added, I need to somehow tell memcached by calling the method that adds the server, assuming such a method exist.