# How to delete memcached key set by another web server

Tags: php, memcached

Consider 2 memcached servers, `mc1` and `mc2` and 2 web servers, `web1` and `web2`, using PHP with Memcached library.

```
$mc = new Memcached();
$mc->addServer(mc1);
$mc->addServer(mc2);
```

From `web1` the following code executes:

```
$mc->set('abc', 'val');
// key is set to mc1
```

Later on, from `web2`:

```
$mc->delete('abc');
```

From what I understand on how memcached library works, `web2` wouldn't know where `web1` has set the key. How can one achieve this?

Right now I'm iterating through the servers and I issue a delete on each. I'm thinking there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiply servers architecture memcached access (set/get/delete) keys on servers based on a hash of the key. So, yes - web2 will not know about deleting on web1. But it is not problem in your situation. Memcache will delete key right from server was placed before.

Please read this question: [Using multiple memcache servers in a pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038094/using-multiple-memcache-servers-in-a-pool/4038108)

Comment: Thank you. I've made a quick test and it worked but I still don't understand how, they're 4 different machines. Maybe mc1 signals to mc2 that it has that key.